# Sinatra + Paperclip; uploaded images have no extension

Tags: sinatra, paperclip, uploading

When uploading images Paperclip is saving files wo/ extensions. I'm using ActiveRecord

photo.rb (model):

```
require "sinatra"

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Paperclip::Glue

    attr_accessible :image

    has_attached_file :image,
        :styles => {
            :small => "100x100#",
            :medium => "500x300"
        },
        :path => "#{settings.root}/public/system/:class/:attachment/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
end
```

photos.rb (controller):

```
post "/photos/?" do
        params[:photo][:image] = params[:photo][:image][:tempfile] if params[:photo][:image]
        @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
        if @photo.save
            { :status => "OK"}.to_json
        else
            { :status => "NOK"}.to_json
        end
    end
```

Comment: Files are saved under names like: `public/system/photos/images/images/000/000/015/original/RackMultipart20120911-4165-1ud8zbh`

Comment: I've tried to use `:basename.:extension` but no luck. Without specifying path, Paperclip have problems because of hardcoded `Rails.root`. So I monkey patched it to Sinatra's root but it changed nothing - still no extensions.

Comment: Because the [:tempfile] refers to a file called RackMultipartXXXX-XXXX. Sadly I'm looking for a solution myself.